Using router to navigate directly instead of using context in async callback?
Here's how my project is build:
I have a router.dart file where the routing is managed
class MainRouter {

GoRouter router = GoRouter {
//...
}
}

I pass this GoRouter object into my MaterialApp.router-Widget:
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
routerConfig: MainRouter.router
//..
)
}

I have the BuildContext as an attribute at my AppEvent.
class AppEvent extends Equatable {
  final BuildContext context;

  const AppEvent(this.context);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [context];
}

Now, I have an asynchronous callback function in my AppBloc where i need to delete something from the database first and then navigate to the home screen.
 void _onAsyncFunction(AppEvent event, Emitter<AppState> emit) async {
    
    await _deleteDatabase();

    event.context.go("/home");
  }

The problem is, I get following lint issue in my project saying: "Don't use 'BuildContext's across async gaps."
I know, according to this question that i can just check with event.context.mounted to be safe the BuildContext is mounted, but i still have that lint issue.
I tried to access the MainRouter.router directly and call MainRouter.router.go("/home") and that worked, but would that violate any architectural rules either of the GoRouter or the Bloc-Architecture?
Thanks for your insights!

Option 1
You could use a BlocConsumer to listen for specific BLoC states, and define a state that would indicate you should go to that route.
class AppPopState extends AppState {
  const AppPopState()
}

An then in your BLoC return that state:
 void _onAsyncFunction(AppEvent event, Emitter<AppState> emit) async {
    
    await _deleteDatabase();

    emit(const AppPopState());
  }

An listen to that state in your widget:
Widget build(context) {
 return BlocConsumer(
   listenWhen: (_, state) => state is AppPopState,
   listener: (ctx, statte) {
       context.go("/home");
     },
   ...


Option 2
Defined a global key for your GoRouter, and use it to navigate from your BLoC.
/// Root navigator key.
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

/// Navigation router.
final GoRouter kRouter = new GoRouter(
  navigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
  ...

 void _onAsyncFunction(AppEvent event, Emitter<AppState> emit) async {
    
    await _deleteDatabase();

    rootNavigatorKey.currentContext!.go("/home");
  }


Thank you for answering, i could do that, but that doesn't answer my question from above.

You question is would that violate any architectural rules either of the GoRouter or the Bloc-Architecture?, the answer is yes, as well to violating linter rules, You are trying to use BuildContext's across async gaps. I have provided two options on how you could change your code to achieve what you want, one for using BLoC and another for using GoRouter directly.

Alright, thank you for making that clear. Could you explain what architectural rules it violates? Why do I violate linter rules? With that "workaround" I don't use the BuildContext across async gaps.

That workaroud may work in most cases, but it is adviced against storing the BuildContext in external (non-wiidget) classes, since it may lead to accessing a context that it is not up-to date (the widget may be rebuilding, for example). For those cases you should use a GlobalKey, or if trying to access it within a statefull object check if the context is mounted.

So, you're saying it is wrong to have the BuildContext as an attribute in my AppEvent? This is a different thing than accessing the MainRouter directly, right?

Yes, they are different things. In your original question text your router config was not stated. If the router field of your MainRouter class is static, you could just use that

Indeed you shall not have BuildContext as an attribute in the class AppEvent
